# How to Get Left Join old ID

Tags: mysql

My tlb_comments are given,this table are tlb_comments table

**tlb_comments :**

```
| ID |  post_id    |   user_id     | comments  |  cm_parent  |  
+----+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
| 11 |      18     |  29           |  Nice     | 11          | 
| 12 |      24     |  30           |  Good     | 12          |
```

tlb_avatar Table are Given ,this table are tlb_avatar table

**tlb_avatar:**

```
| id |  vw_id      |   image                                 |   
+----+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 |      29     |  1510553363_User_Avatar_2.png           |  
|  2 |      30     |  d968c2fe95629e238b04ee34599c5013.jpg   |
```

tlb_viewer Are Given this table are tlb_viewer table

**tlb_viewer:**

```
| id |  name         |     
+----+---------------+
|  1 |      john     |  
|  2 |      Quotos   |
```

My Left Join Query Output.

This Out put was perfect working,but I  want add to the tbl_comments id to The each row.Now time it is does not call the tbl_comments id

```
| id  |  post_id|  user_id | comments|  cm_parent|  vw_id | image |
+----+----------+----------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
|  29 |  18     |   29     |  Nice   |  11       | 29     | 2.png |
|  30 |  24     |   30     |  Good   |  12       | 30     | 2.png |
```

Its Query Output was Good. However I want `tlb comment` Id(tbl_comments id)   to each row.

I'm Explain Given  table. Here we want last column tbl_comments id(comment ID).

This table is I'm Expecting Table.HOW TO GET???????

```
| id  |  post_id|  user_id | comments|  cm_parent|  vw_id |comment ID  |
+----+----------+----------+---------+-----------+--------+------------+
|  29 |  18     |   29     |  Nice   |  11       | 29     | 11         |
|  30 |  24     |   30     |  Good   |  12       | 30     | 12         |
```

MYSQLI QUERY:
That Query is my mysqli query :

```
$qid = $quotos->id;

 $avatar = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tlb_comments LEFT JOIN     tlb_avatar ON tlb_avatar.vw_id = tlb_comments.user_id LEFT JOIN tlb_viewer
                                                        ON tlb_viewer.id = tlb_comments.user_id  WHERE   tlb_comments.post_id = '".$qid."'"  );
                            while($comments = mysqli_fetch_object($avatar)){}
```

Comment: Why are you repeating user_id/vw_id as id? Why are you showing that query? Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Thank You So Much  philipxy.........!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `select *` then the column lists of the joined tables are output in the same order as their tables are joined. If you want the columns in a different order then list the columns.

```
select user_id as id,
    post_id, user_id, comments, cm_parent,
    vw_id, image,
    tlb_comments.ID as 'comment ID'
from tlb_comments
left join tlb_avatar
...
```